# How to add Time Timestamp to DateTime Timestamp?

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, twitter-bootstrap-3, timestamp

I am having a project where I have a time duration for a certain service which I have converted to strtotime and also, I have a datetime picker which I have converted to strtotime, So in my data base, so, I am using a calendar from https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE,

now, here is my problem, in the calendar sample there is the code

```
 {
                        title: 'Long Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
                        backgroundColor: "#f39c12", //yellow
                        borderColor: "#f39c12" //yellow
                    },
```

what I am trying to accomplish is that from the service duration,let's say the duration is 2 hours converted strtotime, how can i add it to the timestamp of datetime? These is my code and screenshot below, as you can see, the result is very wrong since my appoint_end is only 2 hours but the appointment is displayed for days,[image]

```
events:
    [
    <?php $event_query = mysql_query("select * from appointment,service,user where appointment.user_id = user.user_id and service.service_id = appointment.service_id")or die(mysql_error());
          while($event_row = mysql_fetch_array($event_query)){
          $e = $event_row['appoint_date'];
          $ee = $event_row['appoint_end'];
          $eee = $e + $ee;
    ?>
    {
        title  : '<?php echo $event_row['firstname'].' '.$event_row['lastname']; ?> ',
        start  : '<?php echo $event_row['appoint_date']; ?>',
        end: '<?php echo  $eee; ?>',
        allDay: false,
        backgroundColor: "#3c8dbc", //Primary (light-blue)
        borderColor: "#3c8dbc" //Primary (light-blue)
    },
    <?php } ?>
    ],
```

the start date is ok, just the end, since i only added 2 hours from service timestamp to datetime timestamp, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

PHP Time Function:

`time();`

```
<?php
$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
                   // 7 days; 24 hours; 60 mins; 60 secs
echo 'Now:       '. date('Y-m-d') ."\n";
echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', $nextWeek) ."\n";
// or using strtotime():
echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week')) ."\n";
?>
```

This snippet of code returns:

> Now:       2005-03-30
>
> Next Week: 2005-04-06
>
> Next Week: 2005-04-06

Refer to the [php time() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) for more information